# WhenEvent ignores some actions

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

I've got a problem where `WhenEvent` successfully detects an event, but then performs only some of the actions.

In this minimal example, `x[t]` can not exceed `1` (driven by `If`).  If `x[t]` equals `1` in the time window from `0.1` to `0.9`, it should be reduced to `0.2`, toggle a DiscreteVariable, and print the time.

```
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == If[x[t] < 1, 4 x[t], 0],
  WhenEvent[0.1 < t < 0.9 && x[t] >= 1,
    {Print[t], x[t] -> 0.2, dv[t] -> 1 - dv[t]}],
  x[0] == 0.9, dv[0] == 0}, {x, dv}, {t, 0, 1},
  DiscreteVariables -> {dv}][[1]];
(* 0.1 *)
(* 0.502359 *)
```

The two printed times show that the `WhenEvent` was correctly triggered twice -- once when the time window opens at `t == 0.1` and another time later.  But plotting `x[t]` shows that it was not correctly reduced to `0.2` at the second event at `t = 0.502359`.

```
Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However the `DiscreteVariable` `dv[t]` was successfully toggled twice:

```
Plot[Evaluate[dv[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This seems to be an unfortunate interaction with the `If` statement, because changing `x'[t] == 4 x[t]` causes it to work fine.

Bug or just my improper use of `WhenEvent`?  Any ideas for a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly change of the dgl makes your program working:

```
{X, DV} = 
NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == Boole[x[t] < 1.01] 10 x[t] , 
WhenEvent[0.1 < t < 0.9 && x[t] >= 1, {Print[t], x[t] -> 0.2, dv[t] -> 1 - dv[t]}], x[0] == 0.9, dv[0] == 0}, {x, dv} , {t, 0, 1}, DiscreteVariables -> {dv}] ;
Plot[{X[t], DV[t]} , {t, 0, 1}, GridLines -> {None, {1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Seems like the secret sauce in your answer is the `1.01`, not the `Boole`, because changing my original code to `If[x[t] < 1.01` works the same way.  So does `x[t] < 1.00000000001` which is an easy fix and close enough.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know enough about [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent) to say whether the behavior is a bug or not. As a workaround, you can introduce an auxiliary function, and modify the [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent) condition:

```
f[t_] = Piecewise[{{1, .1<t<.9}}, 2];
sol = NDSolveValue[
    {
    x'[t] == If[x[t] < 1, 4 x[t], 0], x[0] == .9,
    h[t] == x[t], h[0] == x[0],
    dv[0] == 0,
    WhenEvent[x[t]>=f[t], {Print[t], h[t] -> .2, dv[t] -> 1 - dv[t]}]
    },
    {x, dv},
    {t, 0, 1},
    DiscreteVariables -> {dv}
];
```

> 0.1
>
> 0.502359

Visualization:

```
Plot[First @ Through @ sol[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting approach! I wonder if this forces `NDSolve` to use a DAE solver.